# How to validate user from photo?

Tags: c#

I'm looking for a method to validate user from photo with C#.

I mean, I'll capture photo from win/web application with webcam and then I'll validate if it is right person...

Is there a easy way to do it? Or is there a way to do it?

Thanks for advance

Comment: ...or the wrong person holding up a photo of the right person

Comment: U can't say that [wife at home and wife at work](http://media.log-in.ru/i/princessa.gif) its same person even without a .NET library so..

Comment: This is fine if it's not a security feature and more of a fun "recognize who's using the system" application. If this is for security reasons, you need to go with something that's much less susceptible to failure.

Answer (score 1):

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705403/net-face-recognition-library (One search, first result...)

If you want to restrict access or something like that, it seems to be very unsecure :o

Answer (score 0):

Find base64 url of the image. It is unique to each and every photo. It gives you a url.

Suppose, if you store it first, in db, then u can use

```
if(newPhotoUrl==dbPhotoUrl){
    Access Granted !
}

/// <summary>
/// Returns the base64 encoded string representation of the given image.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="image">A System.Drawing.Image to encode as a string.</param>
string ImageToBase64String(Image image)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        image.Save(stream, image.RawFormat);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Creates a new image from the given base64 encoded string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="base64String">The encoded image data as a string.</param>
Image ImageFromBase64String(string base64String)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(
        Convert.FromBase64String(base64String)))
    using (Image sourceImage = Image.FromStream(stream))
    {
        return new Bitmap(sourceImage);
    }
}
```

Also, you can also calculate SHA1 or MD5 checksum of the file and compare both

Cannot guarantee anything , just a tip :) Use it at your own risk

Comment: From his post it sounds like he's looking to take a picture of the person and use image processing to determine if the person in the picture is the user he's expecting.

Comment: that's okay, the person just has to sit in the exact same place they did last time

Comment: or after signup, the questioner can give the photo to the user and ask it to make it print and show that :)